# Accessing a path which case sensitive without writing so

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to know whether it possible to access linux path like:
`/home/dan/CaseSensitivE/test.txt`

In a way we write it as `/home/dan/casesensitive/test.txt` and it goes to the right place, means python consider paths as not case sensitive and allow entering them that way, although they are case sensitive.

Comment: That depends on the file system and it's mounting options, usually not. But anyway this is OS related and off-topic for SO.

Comment: The Os is linux centos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Klaus said, the simple answer is no. You could, however, take a more laborious route, and enumerate all folders/files in your top directory (`os.path, glob`), convert to lower case (`string.lower`), test equality, step one level down, etc.

This works for me:

```
import os

def match_lowercase_path(path):
    # get absolute path
    path = os.path.abspath(path)

    # try it first
    if os.path.exists(path):
        correct_path = path
    # no luck
    else:
        # works on linux, but there must be a better way
        components = path.split('/')

        # initialise answer
        correct_path = '/'

        # step through
        for c in components:
            if os.path.isdir(correct_path + c):
                correct_path += c +'/'
            elif os.path.isfile(correct_path + c):
                correct_path += c
            else:
                match = find_match(correct_path, c)
                correct_path += match

    return correct_path

def find_match(path, ext):
    for child in os.listdir(path):
        if child.lower() == ext:
            if os.path.isdir(path + child):
                return child + '/'
            else:
                return child
    else:
        raise ValueError('Could not find a match for {}.'.format(path + ext))
```

Comment: To avoid getting results starting with a double slash (e.g. `//home/user/...`), I think you should rather initialise `correct_path = ''`, but test `os.path.isdir(correct_path + c + '/')`.